# Generate this Bloch sphere in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

I made these images using `Mathematica`:

[image: Bloch spheres]

which I would like to reproduce using TikZ (the axes labels range from 0 to 1). The difficulty is in getting a similar colour scheme that gives the same 3D feel to the image. I have managed to get a basic MWE that recovers the left image:

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}           
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds,fit,decorations.pathreplacing,chains,snakes,angles,quotes}  %TikZ libraries
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, arrows, positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round, line join=round]
\draw[line width=5pt](0,0) circle (8);
\draw [line width=5pt,rotate around={0.:(0.,0.)},dash pattern=on 10pt off 10pt] (0,0) ellipse (8 and 3);
\draw[line width=5pt] [-{Latex[length=8mm]}] (0,0) -- (0,8);
\draw [line width=5pt] [-{Latex[length=8mm]}]  (0,0) -- (-3,-2.75);
\draw [line width=5pt] [-{Latex[length=8mm]}] (0,0) -- (8,0);

\node[circle,shading=ball,minimum width=8cm,opacity=0.4] (ball) at (0,0) {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which generates:

[image: Left image].

This feels a long way from the desired output. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not claiming that this is a precise match of what you get from Mathematica, but the following may illustrate what you can do with rather little effort.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, shadings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round, line join=round]
\draw[line width=5pt,] (0,0) circle (8);
\draw[line width=5pt,rotate around={0.:(0.,0.)},dash pattern=on 10pt off 10pt] (0,0) ellipse (8 and 3);
\draw[line width=5pt] [-{Latex[length=8mm]}] (0,0) -- (0,8);
\draw[line width=5pt] [-{Latex[length=8mm]}]  (0,0) -- (-3,-2.75);
\draw[line width=5pt] [-{Latex[length=8mm]}] (0,0) -- (8,0);

\fill[white,opacity=0.4] (0,0) circle (3);

\shade[right color=orange,middle color=red,left color=blue,opacity=0.3,shading angle=-110] 
 (0,0) circle (3);
\shade[ball color=orange,opacity=0.2] 
 (0,0) circle (3);
\begin{scope}[xshift=17cm]
 \draw[line width=5pt,] (0,0) circle (8);
 \draw[line width=5pt,rotate around={0.:(0.,0.)},dash pattern=on 10pt off 10pt] (0,0) ellipse (8 and 3);
 \draw[line width=5pt] [-{Latex[length=8mm]}] (0,0) -- (0,8);
 \draw[line width=5pt] [-{Latex[length=8mm]}]  (0,0) -- (-3,-2.75);
 \draw[line width=5pt] [-{Latex[length=8mm]}] (0,0) -- (8,0);
 \fill[white,opacity=0.4] (0,0) circle (2 and 6);
 \shade[right color=orange,middle color=red,left color=blue,opacity=0.3,shading angle=-110] 
  (0,0) circle (2 and 6);
 \shade[ball color=orange,opacity=0.2] 
  (0,0) circle (2 and 6);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

More impressive effects may be achieved using fadings.

Comment: Any easy way of changing the point of view?

Comment: @Sid I guess the easiest thing would be to use `tikz-3dplot` to change the view on the coordinate axes, i.e. rotate them. If you also want to change the view but keep the light source fixed, i.e. if you want to move the bright spot of the sphere, then this will become rather involved. In that case, I'd like to argue that you may want to consider using asymptote for that.

Comment: I agree. I will update the question if I manage it. Thanks!